# jQuery scroll() page flickers on hide and show method

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am using jquery.scroll() to trigger hide and show method. When i scroll the page starts flickering. how can i stop that.

My js code

```
    var position = $('#page').scrollTop();
    $(scrollable).scroll(function() {
    // get the  current position of  scroll from #page 
       var scroll = $(scrollable).scrollTop();
      console.log("position" , position);
      console.log("scroll"  , scroll)
      // if initial position < current position  we have not scroll down
      if(scroll > position) {
        $('.notification').hide();   
      } else {
       $('.notification').show();
      }
      // set the initial position to current position of scroll
      position = scroll; 
  });
```

My Html mark up

```
  <div id ="page">
   <div class = "notification"></div>
   <div id = "header"> </div>
  </div>
```

My css

```
 .page{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100%;
 }

  .notification{
    position: sticky
  }
  .header{
    position:fixed
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a missing ; and scrollable was not defined but it does not seem to flicker. Maybe it is something else in your code. I have tested it below.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
  $("#content").append("SOME INFO </br>");
}
var scrollable = $("#content");
var position = $('#page').scrollTop();

    $(scrollable).scroll(function() {
    // get the  current position of  scroll from #page 
       var scroll = $(scrollable).scrollTop();
       
      console.log("position" , position);
      console.log("scroll"  , scroll);
      
      // if initial position < current position  we have not scroll down
      if(scroll > position) {
        $('.notification').hide();   
      } else {
       $('.notification').show();
      }
      
      // set the initial position to current position of scroll
      position = scroll; 
  });
```

```css
.page{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100%;
 }

  .notification{
    position: sticky;
    background: red;
    color: red;
  }
  .header{
    position:fixed;
  }
  
  #content{
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #CCC;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id ="page">
   <div class = "notification">NOTIFICATION</div>
   <div id = "header">HEADER</div>
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

** run the snippet in full page